# How to redirect a subdomain to the main domain at a different port with IIS

Tags: redirects, url-rewriting, iis, plesk, windows

I am trying to set up as following

control.domain.com to http://domain.com:8880/

Plesk is running on that port.

Infact if I would like any website hosted on the server if  accessed with "control.*" should go to http://mywebsite.com:8880/?. Is that possible?. Or we have to write rules for each websites?.

I do not know to enter rule here, so added as a image

[image]

Comment: so when anyone open your site like http://mysite.com , you want to redirect them to http://mysite.com :8880?

Comment: No,when someone visits control.mysite.com, he should go to  mysite.com:8880.

Comment: you site built with asp.net?

Comment: Not all of them. Some of them are php based.

Answer (score 1):

Create a subdomain.
for example: `redirect.mydomain.com`
and add code to index.php (i will use php for redirect):

```
<?php

$header = $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'];
$end_p=strlen($header);
$header=substr($header,5,$end_p);


header("Location: http://$header:8080");


?>
```

save and close.

**Create default dns for control:**

conrtol.domain.com and assign to *redirect.mydomain.com*

Thats all.

When you create a new site. Default dns control.domain.com will assign to new domain.